# How to add more field on shopify store password page

Tags: shopify

I'm creating a Shopify website. Does anybody know how to add more fields on password page instead of just an email field? Please refer the jpg link below.

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8omeK.jpg
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0uj6.jpg

Answer (score 0):

By editing the password template in your theme or by creating one if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Would like to add a field box infront of the email. Any coding need to be adding in or example?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzVJr.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Would like to add a field box infront of the email. Any coding need to be adding in or example?

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzVJr.jpg